# How do I get xml tag values?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

From the data below how do I get the country name as shown in the example output I require (this part in my attempted query `????????????????`)

```
declare @xml xml =
'<animals>
    <dog>
        <country>
            <australia>Perth</australia>
        </country>
    </dog>
    <cat>
        <country>
            <USA>Miami</USA>
        </country>
    </cat>
    <horse>
        <country>
            <Spain>Madrid</Spain>
        </country>
    </horse>
</animals>'

select
    col.value('local-name(.)','char(20)') as animal 
    ,col.value('local-name(country/*/.)', 'varchar(25)') as country /* ?????????? */
    ,col.value('(*)[1]', 'varchar(25)') as city
from @xml.nodes('/animals/*') tab(col)
```

Expected output :

```
animal  country       city
------------------------------
dog     australia   Perth
cat     USA         Miami
horse   Spain       Madrid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shred the XML twice, on child of `animals` level and then on child of `country` level. This way you can select `local-name()` on both elements :

```
.....
select
    animals.value('local-name(.)','char(20)') as animal 
    ,country.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(25)') as country
    ,country.value('.', 'varchar(25)') as city
from @xml.nodes('/animals/*') T1(animals)
 cross apply T1.animals.nodes('country/*') T2(country)
```

**<kbd>[`rextester demo`](http://rextester.com/DMNEC32672)</kbd>**